# OpenLDAP schema files to mimic ActiveDirectory (for dev/test environments)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I support a development environment for an ETL application that interacts with various services, including OpenLDAP. I've setup Docker-Compose with a container for each of the services and datastores this app interacts with so the devs and QA can work in an isolated fashion. The ETL app runs on Linux, so Docker running on our Macbooks works great.

Now, the application needs to talk to ActiveDirectory as well. Docker-Compose on the Mac doesn't support Windows containers, so I cannot use Windows containers and AD-LDS. Since the application uses standard LDAP to talk to both OpenLDAP and AD, I thought it would make sense to create another OpenLDAP container, but with the AD schema instead of the OpenLDAP schema. But, I cannot find schema files that behave like AD. (e.g., CN vs. uid.)

Does anyone know of a set of schema files that do what I'm looking for or do I have to build my own? Or, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you looked into samba?

Comment: @84104 - what exactly do you mean? I'm completely new to Windows (20years in Linux) so I don't know why Samba (the fileshare?) would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `/etc/openldap/schema/samba.schema` file from Samba. (You may need to convert this file from .schema to .ldif using slaptest).
For years Samba has had the ability to act like a Windows Domain Controller.